# Android Tab icon image full size

Tags: android, tabs, icons, size

I have a simple tabController with 4 tabs, but I want the icons images to take up the entire tab. I also want the text for the tab over the top of the icon image. I just need a couple hints to get going in the right direction.

I cannot post images of what my tab looks like (not enough reputation points). But basically I need to get ride of all the padding around the tab icons.

My icons are png file. My tabControllerView is extending TabActivity and I am using a tab_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"            
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout            
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"            
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
                />    
     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

For each tab I am doing this in the onCreate of my tabControllerView:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home", 
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_home)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with something like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++){
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        }
```